Zip contents corrupted when trying to zip via ZipOutputStream in RxJava
I am trying to create a zip file and upload that zip file in AWS S3 via a multipart upload route. However, I am facing an issue where the file is successfully getting generated however, the contents inside the files are getting corrupted.
Here is the error that I am getting when I am trying to unarchive the file :
Archive:  test2MB.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of test2MB.zip or
        test2MB.zip.zip, and cannot find test2MB.zip.ZIP, period.

Here are the code snippets that I have written for this
private Single<List<CompletedPart>> zipAndUploadZipParts(String uploadId) {
        List<Single<CompletedPart>> uploadPartObservables = new ArrayList<>();
        final int[] partNumber = {Constants.START_PART_NUMBER};

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        return zipMetadata(zipOutputStream)
                .andThen(uploadZipPart(byteArrayOutputStream, uploadPartObservables, partNumber, uploadId)
                        .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
                            this.contextRx.log().error(String.format("placeholder", partNumber[0], this.logIdentifier, error.getMessage()), error);
                            return Completable.error(new RuntimeException("Placeholder"));
                        }))
                .andThen(finalizeZipUpload(uploadPartObservables, zipOutputStream, byteArrayOutputStream));
    }

    private Completable zipMetadata(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) {
        return Completable.create(emitter -> {
            try {
                ZipEntry metadataEntry = new ZipEntry(Constants.METADATA_FILE_NAME);
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(metadataEntry);
                zipOutputStream.write(this.catalogObjectsMetadata.getBytes());
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                this.contextRx.log().error(String.format(Constants.LOG_ERROR_ZIPPING_METADATA, this.logIdentifier, exception.getMessage()), exception);
                emitter.onError(new RuntimeException(String.format(Constants.ERROR_ZIPPING_METADATA)));
            }
        });
    }

    private Completable uploadZipPart(ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream, List<Single<CompletedPart>> uploadPartObservables, int[] partNumber, String uploadId) {
        return Completable.create(emitter -> {
            try {
                byte[] zipData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                uploadPartObservables.add(uploadPart(zipData, partNumber[0]++, uploadId));
                byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
                this.contextRx.log().info(String.format("Uploaded part %d for uploadId %s", partNumber[0] - 1, uploadId));
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                emitter.onError(exception);
            }
        });
    }

private Single<List<CompletedPart>> finalizeZipUpload(List<Single<CompletedPart>> uploadPartObservables, ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream) {
        return Single.defer(() -> {
            try {
                zipOutputStream.finish();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return Single.error(new RuntimeException("Error finishing zip output stream", e));
            } finally {
                try {
                    zipOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return Single.error(new RuntimeException("Error closing zip output stream", e));
                }
                try {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return Single.error(new RuntimeException("Error closing byte array output stream", e));
                }
            }
            return Single.merge(uploadPartObservables)
                    .toList()
                    .doOnSuccess(parts -> this.contextRx.log().info(String.format(Constants.ALL_PARTS_UPLOADED, this.logIdentifier, parts)))
                    .onErrorReturnItem(new ArrayList<>());
        });
    }

Can someone guide what is wrong with my code which is corrupting my zip file?
Contents inside the zip file shouldn't get corrupted.

The tag java-stream has nothing to do with your question. Quoting the tag "[...] functional-style operations on streams of values, such as filter-map-reduce pipelines on collections. DO NOT use this tag for questions about Java InputStreams or OutputStreams.". The tag you are looking for is stream.

Your code looks fine, you need to close the zipOutputStream and byteArrayOutput stream before invoking toByteArray() function.
add close statements before the line byte[] zipData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Sample Code for reference:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String dataToCompress = "this is the test string using ZOS";
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.zip");
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(dataToCompress.length());
            ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteStream)) {
            String filePath = "test.txt";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
            zipStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zipStream.write(dataToCompress.getBytes());
            // Close Statements
            zipStream.close();
            byteStream.close();
            byte[] compressedData = byteStream.toByteArray();
            os.write(compressedData);
        }
        System.out.println("File zipped successfully!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

